# Find which method browser used to find location

Tags: javascript, browser, geolocation, navigator

I am fetching location using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`. I am thinking about ignore this location output into account if location is fetched using other ways than GPS (Like wifi, mobile tower etc). Is there a way to figure out how the browser fetched location? My code is given bellow.

```
  var locate = function() {
    showMessage('fetching_location')
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
        send({
          latitude: location.coords.latitude,
          longitude: location.coords.longitude,
          accuracy: location.coords.accuracy,
          status: "geolocated"
        }, 'location_reported')
      },
      function(error) {
        if(error.code == 1)
          send({
            status: "permission_denied"
          }, 'permission_denied')
        else
          send({
            status: 'geolocation_error'
          }, 'not_geolocated')
      },
      {
        maximumAge:10000, timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: You can read the full spec [here](https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/#dom-navigator-geolocation). There doesn't seem to be anything like this.

Comment: You could use the `accuracy` attribute of the response. I guess this would be small for GPS, but high for other methods.